# Web UI for existing Java application

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, lucene, web

I am trying to build a search engine using java and the lucene API as part of a project. For the last step, we plan to build a web UI (a local host would do) for the same. Are there UI softwares/plugins for eclipse which will allow me to call the functions present in the java classes?

Essentially I would want to have a search box and a search key, pressing which will throw up the search results(which is computed from the java program). javascript cannot call java code I understand. So using that is eliminated?

Any suggestions on what to use will be greatly appreciated. I have pretty poor knowledge in front end design!

Cheers!
AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is a simple screen with a entry field and a button and you simply want to return an html table. I would go with a servlet and two jsps. Your servlet can call your search engine and then have the jsp format the data into the table. If you do not know web apis this is probably the easiest entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think, If your using JAVA, that you should look into JSF.
It's a rather easy to maintain and work with library for just the uses you describe.

I recommend these tutorials to get you started: http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Tutorial-Intro

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options to achieve this.
you can create web-ui using jsp.
I have also created same type of project using Lucene, here i have used spring mvc.i have provided all the back-end process as REST api which any web-ui can use.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not look into JSF; it is an overengineered pile for your task.

Sure you can call your java code from javascript, you can make it really simple with something like DWR.

However, for your project I would suggest GWT as then you only deal with Java and it will generate javascript, html and css for you.

For your project you dont really need an "enterprise" level framework like spring or a fullstack JavaEE, you could keep it real oldschool with only JSPs and html/javascript. However thats a bit too flaky for my taste, so go with GWT.

With GWT you basically set it up, define your module, entrance point (look at the hello world), and then you add a layout to your page like something to place the searchbox into and the resultbox to. Then you call your other Java code and classes from there like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use GWT in your application because GWT enables you to call java methods and it will also convert Javascript and css for your Java modules after GWT compile.
GWT reference :- http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use GWT, you could aslo check [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home).

Creating a search UI is really simple, and the tutorial show a criteria /result table application taht could be adapted.